# Enable and disable form fields in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I am trying to enable and disable a field using Javascript, works fine on IE but does not work on Safari.

**FIELDS**
If yes is clicked, should enable free text below, else disabled.

```
<tr id="ContainerQ1266I1396">
<td>Ultrasound Used</td>
  <td>
     <input type="radio" name="Q1266I1396" id="Q1266I13960" onclick="">No</input>
     <input type="radio" name="Q1266I1396" id="Q1266I13961" onclick="regft();">Yes</input>
  </td>
</tr>


<tr id="ContainerQ1267I1276">
  <td>fretext</td>
  <td>
    <input id="Q1267I1276" type="text"size="80" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function regft(){
var regf=document.getElementById("Q1266I13961");
document.getElementById("ContainerQ1267I1276").disabled=true;

 if (regf.checked==true){
    document.getElementById("ContainerQ1267I1276").disabled=false;
 }
}
```

Comment: So how is Yes/No going to toggle when they have different names?

Comment: row id ContainerQ1267I1276 should be enabled if "Yes" is checked else should be disabled.

Comment: now that you changed the names, it would toggle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off the radio buttons don't seem to be in the same group - if you want them to be mutually exclusive options (which is what radio buttons mostly get used for) you could give them the same "name" attribute. See this tutorial for example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_radio.asp

Second, I think you are setting the disabled property on the tr element instead of the input element.  Try:

```
document.getElementById("Q1267I1276").disabled=false;
```